# Moving files containing spaces with mv command

Tags: bash, move

I have the following input.

Entities can be 'MG SOCRATES' 'VALIND' 'SUSBTECT'

This entities have the following directories.

/home/tca/git/tca/<*entity*>

Example :

```
/home/tca/git/tca/MG SOCRATES
/home/tca/git/tca/VALIND
/home/tca/git/tca/SUSBTECT
```

In each directory I have files with this pattern something_or-something.

For example:

```
/home/tca/git/tca/SUSBTECT/asdsad2018-01-01-2018-12-31sdadsda
/home/tca/git/tca/SUSBTECT/asdsad2018-01-01_2018-12-31sdsadadsda
```

I want to move them to a subdicretory for each entity with the following structure.

I have for example this subdirectory.
/home/tca/git/tca/SUSBTECT/2018-01-01_2018-12-31

What I want to do is to move from  /home/tca/git/tca/SUSBTECT/ all files that matches the pattern _or- to the subdirectory.

My code does it correctly but fails for entity 'MG SOCRATES' because there is a space that moves command can not interpretate.

My code:

```
    entity_path="$entity_path""/*"$file_start"*"$file_end"*"
    echo `mv -t  "$path" $entity_path`
```

Where $entity_path all files matching the pattern and $path is the directory where I want to move my files.

I think is a problem about the spaces.

Any idea?

Comment: Read section [§3.1.2 Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html) of `bash` manual

Comment: ``echo `mv -t ...` `` doesn't accomplish anything useful. Just use `mv -t ...`.

Comment: As far as I can tell, all you want is `mv -t "$path" "$entity_path"/*_*`. Don't try to embed the pattern into a variable.

Comment: You cannot have a parameter expansion that undergoes pathname expansion but *not* word-splitting.

Comment: @chepner I think that is the problem, doing the pattern there it works correctly for entities without spaces, but for entities with a space it doesn't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to have a regular parameter expansion that undergoes pathname expansion, but not word-splitting, so your attempt to put the pattern in `entity_path` is going to fail. Either use the pattern directly,

```
mv -t "$path" "$entity_path"/*"$file_start"*"$file_end"*
```

or store the *result* of the pathname expansion in an array.

```
entities=( "$entity_path"/*"$file_start"*"$file_end"* )
mv -t "$path" "${entities[@]}"
```